# In node, how does one concatenate mp3 files using streams

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I'm trying to concatenate a series of mp3 files into one mp3 file and failing miserably.

As far as I can tell, the code I'm using is correct but it's creating a file that contains only the string 'Done'.

```
const dhh = fs.createWriteStream("./dhh-interview.mp3");

clips.forEach((clip) => {
    currentfile = `${dirPath}\\${clip}`;
    stream = fs.createReadStream(currentfile);
    stream.pipe(dhh, { end: false });
    stream.on("end", function () {
      console.log(currentfile + " appended");
    });
  });
```

clips is an array containing the filenames of the files I want concatenating.
I've done a console.log on currentfile so I know it's pointing to where it should.

Comment: You can't concatenate mp3 files as raw bitstreams. You need to read in the file, decode the audio, concatenate the audio streams (it may be stereo for example), re-encode as mp3 (which may result in additional lossy compression) and write the file back out, setting the appropriate meta data, etc. Another option is to write out a file that has chapters, where the two original audio streams become separate chapters, and possibly skip the decode re-encode steps. That still leaves with with not being able to treat it as raw bitstreams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue you're facing is related to how you're using the stream.pipe method and the way you're handling the end event for each stream. The code you provided is trying to concatenate multiple MP3 files, but it's not handling the MP3 file format correctly, which is why you're getting "Done" in the output file.

To concatenate MP3 files properly, you should use a library that understands the MP3 format and can concatenate the audio streams correctly. One such library is ffmpeg, which is a powerful multimedia framework. You can use the ffmpeg command-line tool or a Node.js wrapper like fluent-ffmpeg to achieve this.

Here's how you can concatenate MP3 files using fluent-ffmpeg:

First, install the fluent-ffmpeg library if you haven't already:

```
npm install fluent-ffmpeg
```

Then, use the following code to concatenate your MP3 files:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const fs = require('fs');

const clips = ['file1.mp3', 'file2.mp3', 'file3.mp3']; // Replace with your file names
const outputFilePath = './concatenated.mp3'; // Replace with your desired output file path

const concat = ffmpeg();

clips.forEach((clip) => {
  concat.input(clip);
});

concat
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log('Concatenation finished.');
  })
  .on('error', function (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  })
  .mergeToFile(outputFilePath, './tmp')
  .run();
```

Make sure to replace 'file1.mp3', 'file2.mp3', etc., with the actual file paths of your MP3 files and './concatenated.mp3' with your desired output file path.

This code uses fluent-ffmpeg to concatenate the MP3 files correctly, and it should produce the expected output without the "Done" issue you mentioned.

Comment: I think this is nearly there but I'm getting the following error message: 'Error: No output specified'.

Comment: It seems like you haven't specified the output file for the merged MP3. You should provide the output file path as an argument to the mergeToFile function.

Comment: I've used: const outputFilePath = './concatenated.mp3';

&
```
concat
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log('Concatenation finished.');
  })
  .on('error', function (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  })
  .mergeToFile(outputFilePath, './tmp')
  .run();
};
```

Comment: To clarify my previous comment:
I've set outputFilePath to './concatenated.mp3' & the concat part is exactly as specified above.

Comment: Maybe 2 possibilities : 

    1 ) Ensure that the ./tmp directory exists or choose a different temporary directory for processing

    2) Ensure also that the "clips" array is correctly set.

Comment: I took out '.run()' and everything's working now. Thanks Franck. You've saved me hours of sweat and frustration.

Comment: Perfect ! Don't forget to validate this answer ;)